# Can't install drivers for Epson wp-4530

Tags: dpkg, software-installation

It looks like it's installing ok then I get an error:

```
(Reading database ... 177199 files and directories currently installed.) 
Unpacking epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386 (from .../epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.3.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb) ... 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386: 
 epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386 depends on lsb (>= 3.2). 
dpkg: error processing epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386 (--install): 
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured 
Errors were encountered while processing: 
 epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Tried install under linux mint 14 and ubuntu 12.04 same problem.  Tried installing using cups and Software center.  Driver is from http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX which is only driver site I can find for this printer

Please help

Answer (score 2):

`lsb` isn't in the default installation.  You can check to make sure by running `lsb_release -a`.  If the first line says "No LSB modules are available" then you'll have to add them with:
`sudo apt-get install lsb`
That will install `lsb` and all its dependencies.  Be warned, there's a lot.  My Mint 13 reports:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  alien debhelper dh-apparmor gettext heirloom-mailx html2text intltool-debian libgettextpo0 libjpeg62 libmail-sendmail-perl libqt3-mt libqt4-designer libqt4-gui librpm2
  librpmbuild2 librpmio2 librpmsign0 libsys-hostname-long-perl libunistring0 lsb lsb-core lsb-cxx lsb-desktop lsb-graphics lsb-printing m4 ncurses-term pax po-debconf rpm
  rpm-common rpm2cpio
```

Answer (score 0):

I had successfully installed this printer (WP-4530) on 13.04 on multiple computers, and also on 13.10 on four computers. In each instance, I installed the drivers listed above through the software center, then went to the printer dialogue box and clicked add printer and all was well. On the 5th computer I went to the add printer dialogue box first, it found the printer, then searched for drivers, and during the install, had the error above show up. All of the systems were 64 bit. The error above shows it is searching for 32 bit dependencies. My fix for this was to uninstall what had been done, then install the driver, then go to the printer dialogue box and select add printer, and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into these dependency problems with my WF-3520.
I installed ubiquity-frontend-gtk, and the probelm was solved.

Hope this works for others too.